# Use build configuration on Swift and Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, podspec

I have Swift project in which I have installed my SDK by cocoapods.
In Swift project I have configured `LOCAL`, `STAGING`, and `PRODUCTION` schemes.
When I switch schemes, Xcode recognizes which one to compile, but this is woking only on the Swift project but not ObjC.
Is there a way to change only the Swift project configuration, which will work either on swift and SDK which is installed by cocoapods?

This is my code which must be compiled

```
#if LOCAL
    NSLog(@"SDK: local");
#elif STAGING
    NSLog(@"SDK: staging");
#else
    NSLog(@"SDK: production");
#endif
```

I have tested and it seems working when I include this in my sdk podspec

```
s.pod_target_xcconfig = {'GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS' => 'LOCAL=1'}
```

but in this way no matter which scheme I use, the SDK only compiles the `LOCAL`.

I've seen that some cocoapod libs are installed like this

```
pod 'LIB', :path => '../../', :configuration => ['Debug']
```

but in my case this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Swift can read #define's from a C or Objective-C header file, but not from the configuration. As a solution, put for example CONFIG_LOCAL into your configuration, and a line #define LOCAL CONFIG_LOCAL into a header file that is read by Swift. Any #define with a plain integer constant as its value gets turned into a global variable with an Int32 value in Swift, so then you would write

```
if LOCAL != 0 {
    NSLog("SDK: local")
} else if STAGING != 0 {
    NSLog("SDK: staging")
} else {
    NSLog("SDK: production")
}
```

LOCAL and STAGING must both be defined with integer values in an Objective-C header filer.